# access Database with HeidiSql like PHPMyAdmin (localhost)

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, heidisql

is it possible to access a Database with HeidiSql like PHPMyAdmin, if the DB is only reachable over the web (localhost-Settings).

Comment: Read this: http://blog.webyog.com/2012/10/31/think-beyond-phpmyadmin-to-access-mysql-on-a-shared-host/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, HeidiSQl is the BEST FREE mysql client on Windows.
You can follow this steps:

STEP1: Create a session, Network type choice "MySQL (SSH tunnel)". Hostname/IP as "localhost".
User as "yourmysqllocaluser", so was Password.

STEP2: Select SSH tunnel tab, choice your plink.exe location. SSH host+port use "Remote IP address" and port. Username as "Remote Linux ssh login user", so was Password. If you use Putty Pagent+ssh KEY, then leave the Password field and Private key file blank!

STEP3(IMPORTANT): Use your putty.exe access the Remote IP address, it will prompt a ssh access grant window. Be sure to choice "YES".

STEP4: Back to HeidiSQL, select session and open. Enjoy it as local.

If you havn't do STEP3, open session will occour error.

Answer (score 1):

Since quite a few releases, HeidiSQL natively supports SSH tunnel connections. Just select network type `MySQL (SSH tunnel)` in your session, and set up putty in the upcoming `SSH tunnel` tab.

This is documented in detail on http://www.heidisql.com/help.php#connecting